# Removing headers/footer without losing its contents

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, headers, footers

I've recently converted a PDF to a word doc.

However, it automatically converted parts of the document into headers and footers when it shouldn't, in multiple pages. **Is there a way to convert the headers/footers into regular text?**

Please help!

Comment: Please indicate how you converted the PDF. What program was it? Also a screenshot of the incorrect layout vs. the source may help. It will go a long way toward being able to answer your question.

Comment: Have you looked at opening the header/footer, copying the content, closing the header/footer, pasting the content into the document, and then deleting the header/footer?